# Logback configuration in custom Spring Boot starter

Tags: spring-boot, logging, logback, spring-logback, spring-boot-starter

The purpose of a custom Spring Boot starter is to provide a default Logback XML configuration, e.g.:

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<configuration>
    <include resource="org/springframework/boot/logging/logback/defaults.xml"/>
    <property name="LOG_FILE" value="${LOG_FILE:-${LOG_PATH:-${LOG_TEMP:-${java.io.tmpdir:-/tmp}}}/spring.log}"/>
    <include resource="org/springframework/boot/logging/logback/console-appender.xml"/>
    <include resource="org/springframework/boot/logging/logback/file-appender.xml"/>

    <root level="INFO">
        <appender-ref ref="CONSOLE"/>
        <appender-ref ref="FILE"/>
    </root>
</configuration>
```

It also provides a default `logging.pattern.level` defined in the starter's properties loaded by `EnvironmentPostProcessor`. For instance, let's assume it appends `spring.application.name` to the logging level:

```
logging.pattern.level=%5p [${spring.application.name}]
```

The problems that occur:

- Property `spring.application.name` is not recognized:

> 2023-02-07 09:44:00.704  INFO [spring.application.name_IS_UNDEFINED] 70495 ---...

- The default  `logging.pattern.level` cannot be overridden in the application properties. For example, if the `application.properties` contains the property:

```
logging.pattern.level=%5p stackoverflow
```

```java
@Bean
public String test(@Value("${logging.pattern.level}") String loggingPattern) {
  Logger logger = Logger.getLogger("LogDemo");
  logger.info(loggingPattern);
  return loggingPattern;
}
```

> 2023-02-07 09:57:50.124  INFO [spring.application.name_IS_UNDEFINED] 70880 --- [           main] LogDemo                                  : %5p stackoverflow

If `logback.xml` is not defined in the custom starter the `spring.application.name` is recognized successfully. If `logging.pattern.level` is moved from the starter's properties to the `application.properties` it also works.

It seems like logging is being configured right after loading the starter's properties but before loading the application properties, in case the starter's properties contain the `logging.pattern.level`.

Is there a way to define a default logging configuration without the problems listed above?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I managed to define a default logging configuration in a custom starter using [Spring Boot's extensions to Logback](https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/html/features.html#features.logging.logback-extensions), without additional properties and `EnvironmentPostProcessor`.

> Because the standard `logback.xml` configuration file is loaded too
> early, you cannot use extensions in it. You need to either use
> `logback-spring.xml` or define a `logging.config` property.

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<configuration>
    <springProperty scope="context" name="SPRING_APPLICATION_NAME" source="spring.application.name"/>
    <springProperty scope="context" name="SPRING_LOG_LEVEL_PATTERN" source="logging.pattern.level"/>
    <property name="DEFAULT_LOG_LEVEL_PATTERN"
              value="%5p [${SPRING_APPLICATION_NAME}]"/>
    <property name="LOG_LEVEL_PATTERN"
              value="${SPRING_LOG_LEVEL_PATTERN:-${DEFAULT_LOG_LEVEL_PATTERN}}"/>

    <include resource="org/springframework/boot/logging/logback/defaults.xml"/>
    <property name="LOG_FILE" value="${LOG_FILE:-${LOG_PATH:-${LOG_TEMP:-${java.io.tmpdir:-/tmp}}}/spring.log}"/>
    <include resource="org/springframework/boot/logging/logback/console-appender.xml"/>
    <include resource="org/springframework/boot/logging/logback/file-appender.xml"/>

    <root level="INFO">
        <appender-ref ref="CONSOLE"/>
        <appender-ref ref="FILE"/>
    </root>
</configuration>
```